# Roles of objects and subjects

Tags: grammar, direct-objects, semantic-roles

I am trying to understand the roles of subjects (agentive, identified, characterized, affected, etc) and roles of objects (affected, resultant, eventive, recipient).

> Example 1: Having finished their training, (they) will be fully qualified doctors.

What is the role of "they" in this sentence? Is it used as affected role because "qualified" is an intransitive verb?

> Example 2: Waiting for Ellie, I made (some tea).

What is the role of "some tea"? I feel like it is resultant but I am not so sure.

Comment: "Qualified" wouldn't normally be considered an intransitive verb here. It might be considered an adjective or the past participle form of a transitive verb.

Comment: Why did you put they in parenthesis?? Those terms you are using are not usual in English at all.

Answer (score 0):

Example 1: Having finished their training, (they) will be fully qualified.  "    **"they" is the subject; "will be" + "qualified" = the predicate. "qualified is an adjective, a derivative from "qualify", and serves as the subject complement."Having finished their training" is an -ing clause as adverbial of time.**

Example 2: Waiting for Ellie, I made (some tea).
**"some tea" is the direct object of "made".**

Comment: Thanks but i also asked about their roles. agentive, identified, characterized, affected, etc

Comment: Would you please provide the context for each word?